# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'. Ошибка с сохранением даты

Tags: python-3.x, django, form, datetime

Искал информацию как работать с датой и временем. Не смог найти то что нужно в поисковике. У меня ошибка такого рода:int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'. Скажите как правильно сделать сохранение или направьте в нужном направление?

*Есть форма основная.*

```py
class AdvertisingForm(forms.Form):

    period_n = forms.DateTimeField(help_text='Выберите дату и время!', input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'])
    period_c = forms.DateTimeField(help_text='Выберите дату и время!', input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'])
```

*Функция Save()*

```py
def save(self, post, geography, user):

    model.period_n = datetime.datetime(day=int(post.get('period_n_day')), month=int(post.get('period_n_month')), year=int(post.get('period_n_year')), hour=int(post.get('period_n_hour')), minute=int(post.get('period_n_minute')), second=int(post.get('period_n_second')))
    model.period_c = datetime.datetime(day=int(post.get('period_c_day')), month=int(post.get('period_c_month')), year=int(post.get('period_c_year')), hour=int(post.get('period_c_hour')), minute=int(post.get('period_c_minute')), second=int(post.get('period_c_second')))
```

Comment: скопируйте текст ошибки целиком

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
[14/Jun/2020 13:41:35] "POST /target/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78180

Comment: Полагаю, что вы один из аргументов не передаёте на самом деле. Или имя у него перепутали или ещё что-то случилось. Во-первых посмотрите через `Fiddler`, какой у вас реально идёт запрос, с какими параметрами. А во-вторых залогируйте как-то что у вас в классе `post` приходит в фукнцию `save`. И всё разъяснится, думаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предлагаю подойти к решению проблемы с другой стороны.
Не трогай стандартный формат даты. Тебе в любом случае нужно будет выводить в шаблон ее. В шаблоне модифицируй вывод под свои нужны.

```
{{ some.period_n|date:'значение'}}
```

Вот тут значения https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение. Но это не то, что мне нужно. Сначала я выводил дату, ошибок никаких не было. Можно оставить так, но пользователь должен работать не только с датой, но и временем. Из-за этого возникает ошибка в строчке функции save(). Код с датой был такой
model.period_n = datetime.date(day=int(post.get('period_n_day')), month=int(post.get('period_n_month')), year=int(post.get('period_n_year')))
Но когда начал работать с временем, то все пошло не так. Туплю сильно. Так как не могу найти нормальный пример работы с датой и временем и как это сохранить в бд.

Comment: Время тоже регулируется этими значениями. Я хочу понять, зачем тебе строго сохранять значения в определенном формате. Рано или поздно придётся делать сайт мультиязычным. Придётся переопределять метод. Зачем так хардкодить? Объясни логику работы этой задачи. Может быть, я подкину решение

Comment: Возможно ты и прав. Что код хардкорный. Я учусь только. Дело в том я не понимаю как можно работать с датой и временем. Как я тебя понял, ты предлагаешь через цикл вытащить дату-время в шаблон? Это будет сохранятся в базу данных? Мне формат не важен. Просто хочу разобраться как с датой и временем работать.

Comment: @UltraLink, если дата не будет заполняться пользователем, а должна сама принимать текущее время во время создания объекта, то в models.py в твоём поле добавь значение auto_now_add `period_n = forms.DateTimeField(help_text='Выберите дату и время!', auto_now_add=True)`. В случае, когда дата будет заполняться пользователем, в шаблоне меняй её значение

Comment: Maxim Alyukov. Я вывел значение в шаблон. Но как пользователь будет менять дату и время? Получается время в шаблоне будет не изменяемое. Через форму я думаю было бы проще.  Мои догадки. Через форму не знаешь как то сделать?
Вот как вывел в шаблоне
{{ some.period_n|date:'d.m.Y H:i'}}

Comment: @UltraLink, ты имеешь ввиду в форме указывать дату и время или визуально изменять?

Comment: Форме мне нужно указать правильно формат времени. А уже на сайте пользователь смог сам выбрать дату и время размещение рекламы. Так как у меня проект связан с рекламой и нужно чтобы пользователь выбирал дату начала и конца рекламы.

Comment: Что тебе мешает указать формат в шаблоне? В ответе у тебя указано значение, по которому ты задаёшь формат даты